# Is it possible to create an instance of a variable that's being displayed with data binding?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

My function counts the amount of characters within an input. This function is used on multiple inputs. The function keeps track of character count for each input individually. The remaining characters however are not kept track of individually and any characters into any input count towards a total. How can I display the remaining characters individually for each input within view and still keep my function modular to handle any input it's attached to it? Is it possible to have an instance of the variable for each time the method is called?

Thanks!

```
HTML
    <textarea 
        class="form-control" v-model="HighlightTitle" id="HighlightTitle" v-
        on:keyup="inputCheck">
    </textarea>

    <span>Character Count: {{ charactersRemaining }}</span>

    <textarea class="form-control" v-model="HighlightListing" 
              v-on:keyup="inputCheck" id="HighlightListing">
    </textarea>

    <span>Character Count: {{ charactersRemaining }}</span>     

Javascript

    inputCheck(element)  {

            var characterCount = element.target.value.length;
            var charactersRemaining = '';
            var maxCharacters = 500;

                charactersRemaining = maxCharacters - characterCount;

                this.charactersRemaining = charactersRemaining;

                    if(charactersRemaining < 0) {   
                         this.isOver500 = 1; 
                    }
                    else {
                        this.isOver500 = 0;
                    }
            },
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May I propose a component?

```
Vue.component("counted-textarea", {
  props:["maxCharacters", "rows", "value"],
  template: `
    <div>
      <textarea v-model='taValue' :rows='rows' @input='$emit("input", taValue)'></textarea>
      <span :class="{overMax: isOverMax}">Character Count: {{ remaining }}</span>
    </div>`,
  data(){
    return {
      taValue: this.value
    }
  },
  computed:{
    isOverMax(){
      if (!this.taValue)
        return false;

      return (this.maxCharacters - this.taValue.length) < 0
    },
    remaining(){
      if (!this.taValue)
        return this.maxCharacters;

      return this.maxCharacters - this.taValue.length
    }
  }
})
```

Used like this in your template:

```
<counted-textarea 
             :max-characters="50"
             rows="5"
             v-model="myTextValue">
</counted-textarea>
```

[Example](http://codepen.io/Kradek/pen/VpNvxg?editors=1010).

Comment: Are you creating a new vue file specifically for the Input names?

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data:{
    text1: null,
    text2: null
  }
})

Comment: @pyreal what do you mean? Like a different component for `input` vs `textarea`?

Comment: Sorry I misread that last part. It looks like you're just creating the data objects within the parent class so we can attach the v-model to them. Is that correct? Do you typically break each area down into a component when working in Vue or just when it needs to be reusable?

Comment: @Pyreal Right, I wrote it such that you can use `v-model` on these just like you would with any other input. As to your question, it depends. In this case, you want to scope some data to a particular input so it's an easy choice to write a component. And in Vue2, it's incredibly easy to write one.

Comment: you seem fairly into Vue, Do you know of any resources that help further my understanding on how to go about organizing a application?

Comment: @pyreal when I was starting out, I got a lot out of this course I'll link (just $10 with discount--I have no connection to them). The rest was reading and coding. https://udemyoffer.com/offer/vue-js-2-complete-guide-incl-vuex-coupon/

Comment: @pyreal The teacher of that course also has a nice youtube channel where he covers Vue as well as other frameworks. https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCSJbGtTlrDami-tDGPUV9-w

Comment: Alright, thanks for the recommendation, I'll go through his material.

one more question, when you declare the data 
taValue: this.value it's getting the value from the parent component correct? is this the standard way to get the value for the current target element?

Comment: @Pyreal it's the standard way to implement `v-model` support in a custom component, combined with emitting the input event with the value.  https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Form-Input-Components-using-Custom-Events