# Vuejs: Character Counter

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am trying to create a "twitter-like" character counter using Vuejs; however, I am encountering two separate issues.

1. Error:  Unable to get property 'length' of undefined or null reference
2. Even if I get it to work, is there any way to call the same function using multiple events without adding each one as a separate call to the tag.  Ex: v-on:keyup,blur,focus="limiter(this,140)"

HTML:

```
<div class="form-group" id="vue">
  <label for="eligibility-address-detail">Address Notes:</label>
  <textarea class="form-control" id="eligibility-address-detail" rows="3" 
   name="eligibility[address][detail]" v-model="eligibility.address.details" 
   v-on:keyup="limiter(this, 140)" required></textarea>
  <span class="limiter"></span>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
var main = new Vue({
  el: "#vue",
  data: {
    eligibility: {
      address: {
        details: ""
      }
    }       
  },
  methods: {        
      limit: function(elem, limit){
          var chars = elem.value.length;
          if (chars > limit) {
              elem.value = elem.value.substr(0, limit);
              chars = limit;
          }
          $(elem).siblings('.limiter').html((limit - chars) + " / " + limit + "characters remaining");
      }
  }
});
```

Comment: I answered this pretty much exact question in Vue a while back. http://codepen.io/Kradek/pen/VpNvxg?editors=1010 http://stackoverflow.com/q/43217239/38065

Comment: Looks like there is a problem in your component. In your HTML you have the following `v-model="eligibility.address.details"` but your data attribute does not have those properties.

Answer (score 9):

In general, with most modern front-end frameworks (Angular, React, Vue, etc) you want to avoid manipulating and inspecting the DOM manually. The recommended approach is to make everything data-driven (aka: use the model) and let the framework update the DOM when needed - this is a key concept behind the whole "[reactivity system](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#ad)"

But here are a few recommendations to fix your issue:

Do not call your `limit()` method on DOM events. Instead... look at the `eligibility.address.details` attribute which is are binding to the inputs `v-model`.

You can create a [computed property](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#ad) that calculates the remaining characters based on that attribute.

```
computed: {
    charactersLeft() {
        var char = this.eligibility.address.details.length,
            limit = 140;

        return (limit - char) + " / " + limit + "characters remaining";
      }
}
```

Then in your markup, you would use the computed property like a regular data property:

```
<span class="limiter">{{charactersLeft}}</span>
```

Comment: I had considered using a computed property; however, I would have to create a computer property for every single input I wanted to put a counter on following this example.

Comment: If you have multiple fields with different "max character " values.. then yeah, you would need multiple computed properties.

Comment: @Neve12ende12 are you looking to display the remaining character count AND truncate what they are typing? or just display the character count?

Comment: I am looking to display a count AND truncate what they are typing if it exceeds the count. I will give you a +1 because it does technically answer the question, but I think I will use what Bert Evans commented above.

Comment: Thanks @morficus! exactly what I needed.

Comment: You can accomplish this even more simply using expressions:
`<span class="limiter">{{ 140 - eligibility.address.details.length }} characters remaining</span>`